# Format an AVD ?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have been testing my downloader app on the AVD now and I have run out of the space I allotted. I would like to ask if there is a way to delete all the files that I have on it. `Wipe User Data` gets rid of all the previous apps that I had installed on it.

What I want to do is to delete all the image and video files that I have on it. How can that be done ?

Comment: go to--->settings--->applications--->manage application-->ur application and click "clear data"

Comment: @Indiandroid where is the settings menu ?

Comment: check ur avd it is in first screen only.names as "Settings"

Comment: @Indiandroid oh u mean I follow this sequence after turning on the AVD ? Cool.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can go to:

```
User (Ahmed) > .android (usally hidden) > avd > xxxavd (the emulator) > delete cache or whatever you want.
```

Or from the emulator itself: `Open it > Settings > Applications or Apps > choose an app then clear data & cache.`

& if you want to make it's size greater: `Window > Android virtual device manager > and edit the emulator you want for a greater size.`